# Who manufactures the landing gear on the Airbus A350 series aircraft?

Tags: landing-gear, aerospace-materials, airbus-a350

Where are they made? I assume that they are made out of titanium. Right?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The landing gears are manufactured by Messier-Dowty, a Safran group company. According to [their site](https://www.safran-landing-systems.com/landing-gears/large-commercial-aircraft/airbus-a350xwb-landing-gear),

> Safran Landing Systems is responsible for the design, development, qualification testing, manufacture and support of the main landing gear for the A350-900 aircraft.

Also,

> Safran Landing Systems also provides wheel and carbon brakes for the A350, as well as the landing gear extension-retraction system, monitoring system, steering system and braking system.

The landing gear design [does use large amounts of titanium](https://www.safran-landing-systems.com/sites/nmbd/files/safranls_a350-900_landing_gear_-_english_version_-_mid_def_-_sept_2016.pdf):

> The A350-900 main landing gear ... includes the increased use of advanced materials, in particular high strength titanium, corrosion resistant steels
>   and HVOF coatings.

[image: A350 landing gear]

A350 landing gear materials, from [A350 XWB family & technologies](http://www.fzt.haw-hamburg.de/pers/Scholz/dglr/hh/text_2007_09_20_A350XWB.pdf)

Comment: And the NLG by [Liebherr-Aerospace](https://www.liebherr.com/en/sau/latest-news/news-press-releases/detail/delivery-of-the-100th-nose-landing-gear-of-liebherr-aerospace-for-the-a350-xwb-news.html)

Comment: HVOF coating - looks like pretty intense stuff.  From here https://www.bodycote.com/services/surface-technology/high-velocity-oxygen-fuel-hvof-coating/  "High Velocity Oxygen Fuel (HVOF) coating
High-Velocity Oxygen Fuel (HVOF) coating is a thermal spray coating process used to improve or restore a component’s surface properties ...

Molten or semi-molten materials are sprayed onto the surface by means of the high temperature, high-velocity gas stream, producing a dense spray coating which can be ground to a very high surface finish."

Comment: The billet is made either in Russia or China I think. Especially China since they have the largest press and supplies billets to both Liebherr and Safran.

Answer (score 2):

The A350’s NLG (Nose Landing Gear) is manufactured by Liebherr-Aerospace in Lindenberg, Germany:

> The A350 XWB nose landing gear is the largest landing gear ever to have been developed and produced by Liebherr-Aerospace Lindenberg GmbH (Germany), Liebherr’s center of excellence for flight control systems and landing gears.
>
> Beside the nose landing gear Liebherr-Aerospace supplies the slat actuation system and various key elements of the flaps.

([liebherr.com](https://www.liebherr.com/en/sau/latest-news/news-press-releases/detail/delivery-of-the-100th-nose-landing-gear-of-liebherr-aerospace-for-the-a350-xwb-news.html))

Comment: Welcome to Av.SE!  Can you provide a link to this information? That's helpful so that somebody who would use the info you provided isn't just working off of "somebody on the internet said that..." but has a source to point to.

Comment: I included a quote from the website linked in a comment under the other answer. As Ralph said, please always add a credible source to support your answer (where possible). And @nobody comments are ephemeral, it's better to include all relevant information in answers.